# Gas estimation failed for marketplace contract

Tags: contract-development, remix, erc-20, gas-estimate

i receive an error upon trying to interact with buy function in my contract below

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Market is Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    struct Item {
        bytes32 id; // unique id of the item
        string name; // name of item
        uint256 price; // price of item
        bool isSold; //
        address payable seller; // seller / owner of item
        address payable buyer; // buyer of the item
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => Item) internal items; // mapping of items
    bytes32[] internal itemIds; // mapping of the unique ids of the items

    uint256 internal itemIndex; // counter
    uint256 internal feePercentage = 10; // default fee precentage

    IERC20 internal usdt;
    IERC20 internal teToken;

    /// events
    event ItemListed(bytes32 id, string name, uint256 price, address seller);
    event ItemSold(
        bytes32 id,
        string name,
        uint256 price,
        address seller,
        address buyer
    );

    constructor(IERC20 _usdt, IERC20 _teToken) {
        usdt = _usdt;
        teToken = _teToken;
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0x0d79df66BE487753B02D015Fb622DED7f0E9798d
        );
    }

    /**
     * @notice unique id genrator function
     * @param to  address  of the  item owner
     * @param count  counter
     */
    function generateId(
        address to,
        uint256 count
    ) internal view returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(address(this), to, count));
    }

    /**
     * @notice function that lists an item
     * @param _name  name of item
     * @param _price  price of item
     */
    function listItem(string memory _name, uint256 _price) external {
        require(bytes(_name).length > 0, "Item name cannot be empty");
        require(_price > 0, "Item price must be greater than 0");
        bytes32 itemId = generateId(msg.sender, itemIndex); // generate unique id
        require(items[itemId].id == 0, "Item already exists");

        items[itemId] = Item({
            id: itemId,
            name: _name,
            price: _price,
            isSold: false,
            seller: payable(msg.sender),
            buyer: payable(address(0))
        });
        itemIds.push(itemId); //creating item
        emit ItemListed(
            generateId(msg.sender, itemIndex),
            _name,
            _price,
            payable(msg.sender)
        );
        itemIndex++; // incrementing itemIndex
    }

    /**
     * @notice function that converts price of item to usdt
     * @dev use chainlink Price feeds
     * @param usdPrice price of item
     * @return converted price in usdt
     */
    function getUsdtPrice(uint256 usdPrice) internal view returns (uint256) {
        // ERC20 usdtNew = ERC20(0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955); // contract for usdt

        (, int256 price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData(); // latest price of usdt
        require(price > 0, "Invalid price feed");
        uint256 usdtPrice = uint256(price).div(1e8).mul(10 ** 18);
        uint256 priceUsd = usdPrice.mul(10 ** 18);
        uint256 priceInUsdt = priceUsd.div(usdtPrice);
        return priceInUsdt;
    }

    /**
     * @notice function that converts price of item to $TeToken
     * @dev use API call to coinmarketcap to get price
     * @param usdPrice price of item
     * @return converted price in $TeToken
     */

    function getTePrice(uint256 usdPrice) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 tePrice = 20000000000000000;
        uint256 priceUsd = usdPrice.mul(10 ** 18);
        uint256 newPrice = priceUsd.div(tePrice);
        return newPrice;
    }


    /**
     * @notice function to buy an item
     * @param id  unique id for the item
     */
    function buyItem(bytes32 id) external {
        Item storage item = items[id];
        require(item.id != 0, "Item does not exist");
        require(!item.isSold, "Item is already Purchased");

        item.buyer = payable(msg.sender);

        uint256 price= item.price.mul(10**18);

        if (usdt.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= price) {
            uint256 usdtTokens = getUsdtPrice(item.price);

            uint256 feeAmount = usdtTokens.mul(feePercentage).div(100);

            usdt.safeTransferFrom(
                msg.sender,
                item.seller,
                usdtTokens.sub(feeAmount)
            ); // transfer funds to seller account

            usdt.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), feeAmount); // transfer funds to contract owner 
        } else if (teToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= price) {
            uint256 teTokens = getTePrice(item.price);

            uint256 feeAmount = teTokens.mul(feePercentage).div(100);

            teToken.safeTransferFrom(
                msg.sender,
                item.seller,
                teTokens.sub(feeAmount) 
            ); // transfer funds to seller account 

            teToken.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), feeAmount); // transfer funds to contract owner 
        } else {
            revert("Insufficient funds or wrong payment method");
        }

        emit ItemSold(id, item.name, item.price, item.seller, item.buyer);
        item.isSold = true;
        item.seller = item.buyer;
    }

    /**
     * @dev : return all unique ids for the items
     */
    function getAllItemIds() external view returns (bytes32[] memory) {
        return itemIds;
    }

    /**
     * @dev returning an item based on the unique id
     * @param itemId  unique id for the item
     */
    function getItem(
        bytes32 itemId
    ) external view returns (string memory name, uint256 price, bool sold, address seller, address buyer) {
        Item storage item = items[itemId];
        require(item.id != 0, "Item does not exist");
        return (item.name, item.price, item.isSold, item.seller, item.buyer);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets Fee  Percentage
     */
    function setFeePercent(uint256 _feePercent) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            _feePercent >= 0 && _feePercent <= 100,
            "Invalid fee percentage: fee percentage should be between 1 and 99"
        );
        feePercentage = _feePercent;
    }

    function getFeePercentage() external view returns (uint256) {
        return feePercentage;
    }
}
```

i get an error while using remix idle

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

teToken is a custom token i created for testing purposes.
below is the contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TE is ERC20 {
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 1000000 * 10 ** 18; // Total supply of 1 million tokens

    constructor() ERC20("TE", "TE") {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized where the problem was coming from.. it is the if...else statement in the buy function that was causing the spike in gas estimates. So i created two functions that were to allow transferring of the token to the item seller and contract owner